# Android: Showing wrong screen resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-screen

I was trying to get the screen resolution of android phones,using this code

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    str_ScreenSize = dm.widthPixels + " x " + dm.heightPixels;
    str_ScreenSize = "dd" + " x " + dm.heightPixels;
```

When i tried this code in my Galaxy S phone i got the screen resolution as  320x533 px, but in reality  the Galaxy S got a screen resolution of 480x800 px. So what's wrong with the code??

How can i get the actual screen resolution of a particular device??

Comment: Conclusion about how to get real resolution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824193/htc-sensation-real-resolution

Comment: screen size 600(width) x 1024(height).i get current width  600 but wrong get height 976 (without rotated screen).i get current height 1024 but wrong get width 552 (with rotated screen). please help me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally after 2 days of searching and testing, i finally managed to find out what's the real issue here..
All those above coding will give correct resolution. But the most important this is that we need to mention the target SDK in the manifest file.. Otherwise it will give wrong result if the density is more than 1.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

need to set the targetSDK version from anything between 4-9..
Hope this will help some one in future facing the same issue.

Comment: I spent all day trying to figure out what was happening; it took a long time to realize that getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm) was returning the wrong value!!  After that, the search was simple.  Thanks for saving me some hours!

Comment: I found that you even need to set this in order for the view size to be setup correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: Really bizarre, I was having this problem too but I had targetSdkVersion in the manifest. Realized it should be before the <application> block and sure enough it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:

```
width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Seems like you're getting the pixel after division of the density ( 1.5 ) of Galaxy S.

```
480 / 1.5 = 320
799.5 / 1.5 = 533
```

Edit:

```
density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Comment: ohh..So how can i get the density of a device??

Comment: i am getting the density value for Galaxy S as 1.0

Comment: This seems to be working..though i dont know if its a right method.. DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
              
        density=dm.densityDpi;
        width=(density/160)*dm.widthPixels; 
        height=(density/160)*dm.heightPixels;

Answer (score 1):

Disable pre-scaling by adding this line to your manifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Position:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="...."
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
...
```

After that your display will not be scaled anymore, and you also get the correct display resolution.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int ScreenHeight = display.getHeight();
int ScreenWidth = display.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working..though i dont know if its a right method..

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

density=dm.densityDpi; 
width=(density/160)*dm.widthPixels; 
height=(density/160)*dm.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it:

```
Display dis = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point point= new Point();
dis.getSize(point);
int width = point.x;
int height = point.y;
```

When not in an Activity:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Before getSize was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the getWidth and getHeight methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```