# Wrong widthPixels?

Tags: android, pixel

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

I'm using a "Nexus One"

W shoud be 480 and H shoud be 800 ...

But for me W is 320 and H is 533...

What am I doing wrong???

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    float CAMERA_WIDTH = displayMetrics.widthPixels
            * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    ;
    float CAMERA_HEIGHT = displayMetrics.heightPixels
            * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    ;

    Log.v("" + CAMERA_WIDTH + "---"
            + CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

VERBOSE: 320.0---533.0

Answer (score 7):

Needs a

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Karl, you have to take the screen density into account.  You will need to multiply each of those values by...

```
density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels * density;
int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels * density;
```

That will give you the actual screen size

Comment: Is still not giving me 480x800, only gives me 1,0^^ OR 320 ,0

Comment: your density is returning 1.0?

Comment: Yes Desity is 1.0 for NexusOne

Comment: Karl, not sure why it isn't working for you but you can try the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078808/android-showing-wrong-screen-resolution apparently there is an issue where the target SDK has to be set? let me know if that fixes it!