# Android display.getWidth/height returning wrong sizes for device?

Tags: android

I have a small class that needs to keep track of the devices width and height.

```
public class BrScreenMetrics {
public static int screenX=0;
public static int screenY=0;

public static void setMetrics(Activity activity)
{ 

    WindowManager w = activity.getWindowManager();
    Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
    screenX = d.getWidth(); 
    screenY = d.getHeight(); 


}
```

}

With each new activity i unvoke the line:

```
BrScreenMetrics.setMetrics(this);
```

which updates the values on rotation etc... This works great, except that it is returning 320x522, not my desire's 480x800.
What am i doing wrong?

Slight Update:

I tried it with this code as well using androids own metrics class:

```
    public static void setMetrics(Activity activity)
{ 
   DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);      
   screenX = metrics.widthPixels;
   screenY = metrics.heightPixels;

}
```

but it is still 320x522 :(

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078808/android-showing-wrong-screen-resolution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks looking into the manifest was indeed the right way, I found out in the end i needed

with a minimum requirement of 4-6.

Here is my utility if anyone finds it useful or can offer ways to make it better:

```
package se.brickit.foundation;
//Open comment block above for info.

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;

public class BrScreenMetrics {
    private static int screenWidthPX = 0;
    private static int screenHeightPX = 0;
    private static int densityDpi = 0;
    private static DisplayMetrics metrics;

    public static void setMetrics(Activity activity) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        screenWidthPX = metrics.widthPixels;
        screenHeightPX = metrics.heightPixels;
        densityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;

    }

    /**
     * @return the screenWidthPX
     */
    public static int getScreenWidthPX() {
        return screenWidthPX;
    }

    /**
     * @param screenWidthPX
     *            the screenWidthPX to set
     */
    public static void setScreenWidthPX(int screenWidthPX) {
        BrScreenMetrics.screenWidthPX = screenWidthPX;
    }

    /**
     * @return the screenHeightPX
     */
    public static int getScreenHeightPX() {
        return screenHeightPX;
    }

    /**
     * @param screenHeightPX
     *            the screenHeightPX to set
     */
    public static void setScreenHeightPX(int screenHeightPX) {
        BrScreenMetrics.screenHeightPX = screenHeightPX;
    }

    /**
     * @return the densityDpi
     */
    public static int getDensityDpi() {
        return densityDpi;
    }

    /**
     * @param densityDpi
     *            the densityDpi to set
     */
    public static void setDensityDpi(int densityDpi) {
        BrScreenMetrics.densityDpi = densityDpi;
    }

    /**
     * @return the metrics
     */
    public static DisplayMetrics getMetrics() {
        return metrics;
    }

    /**
     * @return the density
     */
    public static ZoomDensity getZoomDensity() {
        if (densityDpi < 140)
            return ZoomDensity.CLOSE;
        if (densityDpi < 210)
            return ZoomDensity.MEDIUM;
        return ZoomDensity.FAR;
    }

    public static int getStatusBarHeight() {
        ZoomDensity zd = getZoomDensity();

        if (zd == ZoomDensity.CLOSE)
            return 19;
        else if (zd == ZoomDensity.MEDIUM)
            return 25;
        else 
            return 38;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you get the right dimensions of the screen with dp , 
 if you want to get the real dimensions in pixels , add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supported-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Note : that's possible only on Android 1.6 sdk , or higher

Hope it helps :)