# Android: Screen Density is Not Being Reported Correctly

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen

In the course of developing my Android application, I noticed that the following lines of code were not reporting the correct screen size for my Samsung Nexus S:

```
width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Width was returned as 320, while height got set to 533. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078808/android-showing-wrong-screen-resolution) I know that this is a problem relating to the pixel density of the device not being taken into account. To correct for this, I wrote up the code below:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int density = dm.densityDpi; 
int width = (density / 160) * dm.widthPixels; 
int height = (density / 160) * dm.heightPixels;
```

When I toast the variables `width` and `height`, the returned dimensions are 320 wide and 533 tall, meaning that nothing changed. Furthermore, `dm.densityDpi` returns 160, and not 235, as it should for the Samsung Nexus S.

Some posts that I have read, seem to suggest that the problem might lie within the AndroidManifest.xml. I have already added the following to my XML file in an attempt to solve this issue:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"
/>

<supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
/>
```

But, alas, this has not worked either. So, does anyone know how I can get the phone to correctly return its density?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "problem" has nothing to do with density, it's because your application runs in compatibility mode. Your manifest must report anyDensity=true.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. I guess when I included that line I made the assumption that setting it to false would force it to use the phone's native density... I should have read the docs more closely. Thank you!