# unable to get display metrics

Tags: java, android, screen-resolution, getresource

I am making a game that displays animated characters on the screen
Now I am at the stage where i want it to display correctly on other devices as well
increase the screen resolution on my own device and have it still display correctly
for this I want to get the scale factor so I can change all my pixel values to DP values
however the display metrics does not change no matter what I change the screen resolution to

for example

```
this.getHolder().setFixedSize(1024, 768);
scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
    .getMetrics(dm);
float xDpi = dm.xdpi;
float yDpi = dm.ydpi;
```

Now no matter what I change 'setfixedsize ' to, both xdpi and scale stay the same even though it does show the increased screen resolution on the display

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078808/android-showing-wrong-screen-resolution?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can get display metrics using below line.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Comment: As I stated in my question. My issue is not getting the displaymetrics. My issue is understanding why  when I change resolution using setFixedSize the displaymetrics dont change, yet my screen shows a different resolution

Comment: I don't think you can actually change the values of device displaymetrics, you will have to read displaymetrics and change the size of your layouts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for display wallpaper may be its help full=====>

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    float w = size.x;
    float h = size.y;
    width = ((w)/1000);
    height = ((h)/1000);
    Log.d("width===>", String.valueOf(width));
    Log.d("height===>", String.valueOf(height));
```

> (OR)

```
    metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float w=metrics.widthPixels;
    float h=metrics.heightPixels;

    width = ((w)/1000);
    height = ((h)/1000);
    if(width == 0.72f && height == 1.28f){
        width=1.08f;
        height=1.776f;

    }
    Log.d("width===>", String.valueOf(width));
    Log.d("height===>", String.valueOf(height));
```